# Why does calling modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>() add a configuration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to add domain types to the context on the fly. Overriding `OnModelCreating`, adding the type and configuring the added type is very natural way I assumed:

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfig())(); // throws exception            
    }
}

class MyEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
}
```

But surprisingly, `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfig())()` throws the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: A configuration for type 'MyEntity' has already been added. To reference the existing configuration use the Entity() or ComplexType() methods.

Inspecting `modelbuilder.Configurations` revealed that calling `.Set<T>` causes a configuration to be added automatically.

Any solution?

Comment: Shouldn't the configuration be added before the set is constructed?

Comment: I'm using EF6, and I don't see an invokable `Set<T>()` on `DbModelBuilder `.  Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: Do you have automatic migrations turned on?

Comment: @E-Bat No, it is turned off

Comment: @DavidL You gave the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hans glad it helped :).  I couldn't be certain it was the answer without testing it, but glad it worked :)

Comment: Oh, so you edited that offending line again?  Talk about wanting to confuse us with your question.  I'm glad you got it working though.

Comment: @sstan Sorry about that. But you pointed out the main source of error in your answer and that was enough to resolve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to sstan and DavidL the correct order of execution of the commands is:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfig())(); 
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your post ***was*** mistaken (before you edited your post).  You must be referring to `DbContext.Set<T>`, not `DbModelBuilder.Set<T>`.

And if that's the case, you are not supposed to call `DbContext.Set<T>` from inside `OnModelCreating`, it just doesn't make sense.

You can use `DbContext.Set<T>` to get a reference to a db set.  But to get that db set, EF first has to make sure that all the configurations are initialized, if it hasn't already done so.  So, calling `DbContext.Set<T>` for the first time will actually indirectly ***trigger*** a call to `OnModelCreating`.

I can't even begin to imagine what is actually happening when you call `DbContext.Set<T>` from within the `OnModelCreating` method.  Maybe it's just creating some default configuration on the fly, because it never got a chance to finish initializing the configurations by the time that line got called, I can't be sure.

Comment: This is the point: you are not supposed to call `DbContext.Set<T>` from inside `OnModelCreating`, I mo

Comment: @Hans: That's right. `OnModelCreating` is for initializing the entity configurations only.  You can't start playing with entities (using `DbContext.Set<T>`) before they are actually initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you Referenced the **Correct Class** inside your **Mapping Class**.

```
 public class MyEntityMap: InsightEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
```

I realized I've done this before when creating new classes , just by copying existing classes, and not analyzing them appropriately.